# How to get alternate colors div with pure css and with IE 7 support?

Tags: css, xhtml

This is HTML.

```
<div class="container">
            <div> background of this i need in white </div>
            <div> background of this i need in red </div>
            <div> background of this i need in white </div>
            <div> background of this i need in red </div>
        </div>
```

I want to select alternate div without adding class or id .

Is it possible with CSS only (no Javascript) with **IE 7** support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE7 doesn't support the selector you would require, which is `:nth-child()`.

Generally you would use

```
.container div:nth-child(even) {
     background: red;
}
```

IE7 [does not support it](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild#compatibilitysection), unfortunately.

You will need to use JavaScript, or add a class to every odd or even row (perhaps using a server side language).

Comment: can't we select every second `div` inside `<div class="container">`?
http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/ie7-commands.shtml

Comment: @metal-gear-solid It should work in IE9 - according to the compatibility charts on the page linked it is not supported in IE8.

Comment: +1 for linking to sitepoint instead of w3schools ;) And yes, IE up to and including version 8 does not support CSS3.

Answer (score 3):

> can't we select every second div inside `<div class="container">` [with the CSS2 selectors introduced by IE7]?

Well kind of, with the adjacency selector:

```
.container div { background: white; }
.container div+div { background: red; }
.container div+div+div { background: white; }
.container div+div+div+div { background: red; }
```

But that means writing out a rule (of increasingly unwieldy length) for each child. The above covers the example markup with four children, so it's manageable for short, fixed-number-of-children elements, but impractical for elements with a large or unlimited number of children.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done.

Comment: not possible with any CSS selectors combination? IE6 support is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Use in-line style tags, like, 
the following works in IE 7
not tested for others.

```
<div style="background-color:#ffff00" > Hello YOU div</div>
```

Comment: I'd say adding a class would be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
div:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#ffffff; }
div:nth-child(even) { background-color:#ff0000; }
```

but i don't know (and can't test) if this works in IE7 - if not, you'll have to use different classes for the divs.